# Error al grabar (loop)

Tags: android-studio

Muy buenas comunidad esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien, les comento que estoy realizando mi primera app para android con java, en a cual utilizo fragments, son 4 tablas con las que opero las cuales se almacenan en mysql, pero la ultima es la que me da problema ya que realiza un loop y  no entiendo el porque, este es el proceso que se hace, una vez que termina de grabar la ultima tabledlayout siempre y cuando cumpla con un requisito, si graba hace este proceso:

```
String URL = "http://192.168.1.**/gestion/insertar_factura2.php";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                buscar6();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
```

siguiendo con la lógica presento el buscar6():

```
private void buscar6() {
    String url = "http://192.168.1.**/gestion/buscar_factura4.php?N_Factura=" + txtfactura.getText().toString();
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            if (response.length() > 0) {
                try {
                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(0);
                    txtfactura.setText(jsonObject.getString("N_Factura"));
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Este registro ya ha sido ingresada.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    eliminar_factura3("http://192.168.1.**/gestion/eliminar_factura3.php");
                } catch (JSONException e){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                if (Integer.parseInt(txtrepuesto.getText().toString()) > 0) {
                    buscar7();
                }
                ejecutarServicio1("http://192.168.1.**/gestion/insertar_factura3.php");
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Error de conexión", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

ahora como se que existe el N_Factura = 100 se encuentra ya grabado con anterioridad se dirige al eliminar ese campo:

```
private void eliminar_factura3 (String URL) {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            ejecutarServicio1("http://192.168.1.**/gestion/insertar_factura3.php");
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
            parametros.put("N_Factura", txtfactura.getText().toString());
            return parametros;
        }
    };
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

hasta ahí todo bien no hay problema, se elimina el registro ya existente y se dirige al ejecutar:

```
private void ejecutarServicio1 (String URL) {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Datos grabados satisfactoriamente.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Limpiardatos();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String w = "0";
            int valorBoleta = Integer.parseInt(w);
            txtboleta.setText(String.valueOf(valorBoleta));
            parametros.put("Nombre_Compañia",txtnombre.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Rut_Compañia",txtrut.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("N_Factura",txtfactura.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("N_Boleta",txtboleta.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Fecha_Emision",txtfecha1.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Total_Venta",txttotal.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Todos",txttodos.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Activo",txtactivo12.getText().toString());
            return parametros;
        }
    };
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

es qui en donde me registra el problema, según lo indicado:

```
2023-10-12 16:15:55.678 9319-9319/? E/USNET: USNET: appName: com.example.prueba
2023-10-12 16:15:55.832 9319-9319/com.example.prueba E/.example.prueb: Attempt to load writable 
dex file: /data/data/com.example.prueba/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex
2023-10-12 16:21:16.301 9319-10594/com.example.prueba E/Volley: [897] 
NetworkDispatcher.processRequest: Unhandled exception java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 1, 1
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 1, 1    
    at android.text.PackedIntVector.getValue(PackedIntVector.java:75)
    at android.text.DynamicLayout.getLineTop(DynamicLayout.java:1010)
    at android.text.Layout.getLineBottom(Layout.java:1722)
    at android.widget.TextView.invalidateRegion(TextView.java:8215)
    at android.widget.TextView.invalidateCursor(TextView.java:8183)
    at android.widget.TextView.spanChange(TextView.java:12070)
    at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onSpanAdded(TextView.java:15238)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendSpanAdded(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1298)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:788)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:687)
    at androidx.emoji2.text.SpannableBuilder.setSpan(SpannableBuilder.java:140)
    at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:96)
    at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:78)
    at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:153)
    at android.text.method.ArrowKeyMovementMethod.initialize(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.java:325)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6984)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6801)
    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:140)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6753)
    at com.example.gestion.archivos.factura$55.getParams(factura.java:1317)
    at com.android.volley.Request.getBody(Request.java:480)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:283)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:257)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.executeRequest(HurlStack.java:89)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:104)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:132)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)
2023-10-12 16:21:18.761 9319-10791/com.example.prueba E/Volley: [1052] 
NetworkDispatcher.processRequest: Unhandled exception java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 1, 1
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 1, 1
    at android.text.PackedIntVector.getValue(PackedIntVector.java:75)
    at android.text.DynamicLayout.getLineTop(DynamicLayout.java:1010)
    at android.text.Layout.getLineBottom(Layout.java:1722)
    at android.widget.TextView.invalidateRegion(TextView.java:8215)
    at android.widget.TextView.invalidateCursor(TextView.java:8183)
    at android.widget.TextView.spanChange(TextView.java:12070)
    at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onSpanAdded(TextView.java:15238)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendSpanAdded(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1298)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:788)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:687)
    at androidx.emoji2.text.SpannableBuilder.setSpan(SpannableBuilder.java:140)
    at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:96)
    at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:78)
    at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:153)
    at android.text.method.ArrowKeyMovementMethod.initialize(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.java:325)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6984)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6801)
    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:140)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6753)
    at com.example.gestion.archivos.factura$55.getParams(factura.java:1317)
    at com.android.volley.Request.getBody(Request.java:480)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:283)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:257)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.executeRequest(HurlStack.java:89)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:104)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:132)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)
```

por lo de la linea 1317 es esta la secuancia completa:

```
String w = "0";
int valorBoleta = Integer.parseInt(w);
txtboleta.setText(String.valueOf(valorBoleta));
```

además les presento el arreglo json en php y realizado en visual studio code:

```
<?php
header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
require("conexion1.php");
$conexion = retornarConexion();
$Nombre = $_POST['Nombre_Compañia'] ?? null;
$Rut = $_POST['Rut_Compañia'] ?? null;
$Factura = $_POST['N_Factura'] ?? null;
$Boleta = $_POST['N_Boleta'] ?? null;
$Fecha = $_POST['Fecha_Emision'] ?? null;
$Total = $_POST['Total_Venta'] ?? null;
$Todos = $_POST['Todos'] ?? null;
$Activo = $_POST['Activo'] ?? null;
$consulta = "INSERT into fac_boleta1 (Nombre_Compañia,Rut_Compañia,N_Factura,N_Boleta,Fecha_Emision,Total_Venta,Todos,Activo)
values ('".$Nombre."','".$Rut."','".$Factura."','".$Boleta."','".$Fecha."','".$Total."','".$Todos."','".$Activo."')";
echo "se graban los datos";
mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta) or die ("Problemas al insertar".mysqli_error($conexion));
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
con  la imagen ahí se pueden dar cuenta de mi problema que vuelve a grabar no se el motivo del porque lo realiza si elimina bien el registro ya existente es decir el N_Factura = 100, lo graba bien y posteriormente lo graba como N_Boleta = 0,es por eso que realiza ese loop, he estado todo el día en esto y ninguna solución, ojala que me puedan ayudar soy novato en estas lides y me gusta aprender, trato de no molestar mucho en la comunidad, pero cuando no puedo solucionarlo me dirijo hacia Uds, y desde ya muchas gracias.
PD. si necesitan algo más no duden ensolicitarlo y desde ya muchas gracias.